# Magnolia Combobox customized dont display

Tags: combobox, content-management-system, jcr, magnolia

I'm using magnolia cms and I created a customized combobox with com.vaadin.ui.CustomField and it saves values in jcr, but when I try edit a node in my app, the value previously saved dont displayed. Someone has any hints why this happens and how can i solve it?

thank you all in advance

Mário

Answer (score 0):

If you have created it by extending Magnolia's `SelectFieldFactory` you probably need to extend `info.magnolia.ui.form.field.factory.SelectFieldFactory#createDefaultValue(Property<?> dataSource)` method.
If you have created your field by other means, most likely you need to look somewhere between your datasource and place where you initialize the field and fill it with values.